# update sharedpreferences inside a class automatically

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an seperate "FirebaseUserProfile" class which adds and updates user info on both the app and at the firebase database. Until now I have been using sharedpreferences on my MainActivity.java, but I now want to move this in to FirebaseUserProfileClass so I easily can update user info across the app.

Below you see my code in the class how I want to do it. First the method for saving the sharedpreferences:

```
 public void saveDataForPreferences(Context context, String hasUserAlreadySeenTheIntroMessage, String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(hasUserAlreadySeenTheIntroMessage, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, hasUserAlreadySeenTheIntroMessage);
    editor.apply();
}
```

And then my method which add the "desired" information into this method above:

```
public void addPersonalInfoToDB(final Context howToDoThis){ // is this correct?

    Query secretNotesQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdditionalUserInfo");
    secretNotesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //final DatabaseReference current_notes_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdditionalUserInfo").push();
            final DatabaseReference current_notes_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yo").push();
            Map extraUserInfo = new HashMap();
            extraUserInfo.put("sex", sex);
            extraUserInfo.put("user-age", age);
            extraUserInfo.put("user-weight", weight);
            extraUserInfo.put("intro-message-seen", introMessageSeen);
            extraUserInfo.put("user_id", getUid());

            saveDataForPreferences(howToDoThis, introMessageSeen,"2");


            current_notes_db.setValue(extraUserInfo);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

and inside my "ProfileCompletionActivity":

```
the_firebase_profile_class.addPersonalInfoToDB(); // What i can i put inside this parameter?
```

I get the error:

```
method addPersonalInfoToDB in class FirebaseUserProfile cannot be applied to given types;

required: Context

found: no arguments
```

Could someone help me with this? thank you.

EDIT: Also a method where I can read the sharedpreferences:

```
    public int readSharedPreference(Context context,String lol ,String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(lol, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return temp = sharedPreferences.getInt(key,DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: `ProfileCompletionActivity` reference e.g `the_firebase_profile_class.addPersonalInfoToDB(this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple put **Activityname.this** in parameter of function. In your case replace this line

```
the_firebase_profile_class.addPersonalInfoToDB();
```

to this line

```
the_firebase_profile_class.addPersonalInfoToDB(ProfileCompletionActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Context` is for most practical purposes an instance of an `Activity` or `Application`, so one way is to pass a reference to your calling `Activity` as a parameter to the `addPersonalInfoToDB` function.

Also, when you invoke `context.getSharedPreferences(hasUserAlreadySeenTheIntroMessage, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`, make sure to pass a constant value to the first argument, which is an identifier of a preferences file. You have to pass a constant value, imagine a name like `"storage"`, so you always save and retrieve from the same file, like:
`context.getSharedPreferences("storage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: Extra question: I have now added a method to read the sharedpreferences:

    public int readSharedPreference(Context context,String lol ,String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(lol, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return temp = sharedPreferences.getInt(key,DEFAULT);
    }

How can I test this method on activity to check whetever data actually has been saved and show this in a e,g. Toast message?

Comment: if you want to check the result of storing data in the preferences, use the `commit` method instead of `apply` and check the returned value.